# addCircles requires non-NULL latitude and longitude values

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, leaflet

I am new to shiny. I want to plot a bunch of points on a map and have them show up with a radius that is a function of a specific column in the `master` dataframe.

My data:

```
   notation label lat   long date                 determinand value unit
0  a        site1 12.10 3.5  2000-01-11T12:45:00  item1       17    km/h
1  b        site2 12.14 3.6  2000-01-11T12:45:00  item2       11    kg
2  c        site3 12.11 3.7  2000-01-11T12:45:00  item1       5     km/h
3  d        site4 12.15 3.8  2000-01-11T12:45:00  item2       86    kg
```

My code:

```
# Libraries
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(plotly)
library(modeldata)
library(DataExplorer)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)
require(reshape2)
library(purrr)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Make API call to get locations
res1 <- GET("http://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/id/sampling-point?&area=1-1") # area=1-1: East Anglia # nolint
data1 <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res1$content), flatten = TRUE)
items1 <- data1$items
coords <- select(items1, c("notation", "label", "lat", "long"))
df1 <- data.frame(coords)

# Make API call to get data for all locations in df1
ids <- df1$notation
url <- "http://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/data/measurement?"
df2 <- data.frame()
for (id in ids) {
  res2 <- GET(url = url, query = list(samplingPoint = toString(id))) # nolint
  data2 <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res2$content), flatten = TRUE)
  items2 <- data2$items
  values <- select(items2, c("sample.samplingPoint.notation", "sample.samplingPoint.label", "sample.sampleDateTime", "determinand.label", "result", "determinand.unit.label")) # nolint
  df <- data.frame(values)
  df2 <- rbind(df2, df)
}

# Change df2 colnames
colnames(df2) <- c("notation", "label", "date", "determinand", "value", "unit")

# Add lat and long values to df2 from df1
temp <- left_join(df1,df2, by='notation')
master <- temp[, c("notation","label.x","lat","long","date","determinand","value","unit")]
colnames(master) <- c("notation", "label","lat","long","date","determinand","value","unit")
point_data <- master[, c("notation","label","lat","long")]
determinands <- sort(unname(unlist(distinct(master["determinand"]))))


# Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  tags$head(tags$style('.selectize-dropdown {z-index: 10000}')),
  sliderInput("date", "Date", min=as.Date(min(master$date)), max=as.Date(max(master$date)), value=as.Date(min(master$date))),
  selectInput("select", "Determinand", choices = determinands),
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Filter data according to determinand and time
  data <- reactive({
    master[master$determinand==input$select & master$date == input$date]
  })
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    radius=data()$value
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addRectangles(
      lng1=1.5, lat1=51.3,
      lng2=-1.5, lat2=53.3,
      fillColor = "transparent",
      color="#000000",
      weight=2,
      opacity=1
      ) %>%
    addCircles(lng=data()$long,lat=data()$lat, radius=radius, color="#000000", label=data()$label, opacity=1, fillOpacity=0.5) 
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

The error message:

```
Warning: Error in validateCoords: addCircles requires non-NULL latitude values
```

However, my `lat` and `long` columns *are* non-NULL!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

1. There is a small error in the reactive filter: Column indicator is missing

   data <- reactive({
   master[master$determinand==input$select & master$date == input$date, ]
   })
2. In the default choices of inputs: master$determinand == "1,1-Dichloro" and master$date == as.Date("2000-01-05") there is no data after filtering, giving `Warning: Error in validateCoords: addCircles requires non-NULL latitude values`

Full APP code:

```
# Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  tags$head(tags$style('.selectize-dropdown {z-index: 10000}')),
  sliderInput("date", "Date", min=as.Date(min(master$date)), 
               max=as.Date(max(master$date)), value=as.Date(min(master$date))),
  selectInput("select", "Determinand", choices = determinands, selected = "pH"),
  leafletOutput("mymap")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Filter data according to determinand and time
  data <- reactive({
    master[master$determinand==input$select & master$date == as.Date(input$date),  ]
  })
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    if(data() %>% nrow() > 0 ){
      
      radius=data()$value
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addRectangles(
          lng1=1.5, lat1=51.3,
          lng2=-1.5, lat2=53.3,
          fillColor = "transparent",
          color="#000000",
          weight=2,
          opacity=1
        ) %>%
        addCircles(lng=data()$long,lat=data()$lat, radius=radius, color="#000000", label=data()$label, opacity=1, fillOpacity=0.5)
      
    }  
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```